# Combine public key with private key and CA to PFX using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, pfx

how do I combine certificate with private and CA into pfx file so that they all can be installed in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

These certs are generated from https://www.sslforfree.com

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey private.key -certfile ca_bundle.crt -out certificate_merged.pfx